# How can I do a two way data biding using date picker?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use the date picker component from Vuetify. My Date comes from my C# which DateTime is the format. How Can I do a two-way data binding using verify date picker?

I wanna show a previous date a allow the user to change it or not.

Thanks

```
<v-menu ref="menu" v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" :return-value.sync="date" lazy transition="scale-transition" offset-y full-width min-width="290px">

<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

  <v-text-field v-model="**editedItem.activationdate**" label="Picker in menu" prepend-icon="event" readonly v-on="on"></v-text-field>

</template>

<v-date-picker v-model="**editedItem.activationdate**" no-title scrollable>

<v-btn flat color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
 <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(editedItem.activationdate)">OK</v-btn>
</v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the C# DateTime-object to JavaScript Date-object. In JS you can create a Date object by passing in the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 (new Date(0) will give you 1970-01-01). For getting this number you can use an extension like:

```
 public static class DateTimeExtensions
 {
    private static readonly long DatetimeMinTimeTicks =
        (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).Ticks;

    public static long ToJavaScriptMilliseconds(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return (long)((dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000);
    }
  }
```

So now you can in the backend do for instance:

```
long numberOfMilliseconds = DateTime.Now.ToJavaScriptMilliseconds(); //C#
```

And send that to the frontend so you can do this with JavaScript:

```
var myDate = new Date(editedItem.numberOfMilliseconds); //JavaScript
```

Comment: Sorry, should I do this in the backend and send a Javascript time to the front end? Is it that?

Comment: Yes, kinda, I edited my answer with more elaboration

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I am now receiving the following error: this.lastValue.split is not a function

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use a variable as a function. I need a little more info to be able to help you. Where are you using this code? Are you passing it to a method?